# Mouse coordinates relative to Div inside parent div with scrolls

Tags: jquery, css

I have two Divs inside a parent Div ( overflow: auto)  the two Divs are big so I get scrolls for the parent, the problem is that I get variable mouse coordinates(onclick Event) for the inside Divs when I scroll up and down (sometimes even minus value) here is how I calculate relative value of mouse

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#MnDiv").click(function(e){
var clientXRel = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
var clientYRel = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
var clientCoordsRel = "( " + clientXRel  + ", " + clientYRel  + " )";
$("span:first").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);
$("span:last").text("( clientXRel  , clientYRel  ) : " + clientCoordsRel
+      " ( offsetLeft  , offsetTop  ) : " + this.offsetLeft+ ", " this.offsetTop); 
});
```

So the Question is How to get the right coordinates relative to the inside Div no matter where the scroll is?
The complete Example(jsfiddle) [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alamin84/PNLU3/embedded/result/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the jQuery event varibles `.pageX` and `.pageY` and the element offset function `.offset().top` and `.offset().left`

so it will look like

```
var clientXRel = e.pageX- $(this).offset().left;
var clientYRel = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PNLU3/3/

Comment: When I try and implement this in a bit of code I have, I'm getting an error: " 'offset().left' is null or not an object". Any thoughts on why this might come up? Could it be 'this' not acutally referring to anything if it's being used in a method isolated from the acutal event?

Comment: are you sure 'this' is the clicked element when you call the code?